# Switch to column for certain category because of database input error

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

My database have this type of error, for some item category `Snacks` is misplaced with price. I want to switch I need to switch the columns. Here's my data

```
Id   Item_category     Price
1    Food              647
2    Drinks            672
3    Food              627
4    Drinks            678
5    679               Snacks
6    742               Snacks
7    Snacks            743 
8    Drinks            689
```

What the database what I need

```
Id   Item_category     Price
1    Food              647
2    Drinks            672
3    Food              627
4    Drinks            678
5    Snacks            679
6    Snacks            742 
7    Snacks            743 
8    Drinks            689
```

Comment: what question? I still accept if answer came before dupe detected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) for boolean mask and then swap values by 2d numpy array:

```
mask = df['Item_category'].str.isnumeric()
#if necessary check numeric
#mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Item_category'], errors='coerce').notnull()

df.loc[mask, ['Item_category','Price']] = df.loc[mask, ['Price','Item_category']].values
print (df)
   Id Item_category Price
0   1          Food   647
1   2        Drinks   672
2   3          Food   627
3   4        Drinks   678
4   5        Snacks   679
5   6        Snacks   742
6   7        Snacks   743
7   8        Drinks   689
```

Comment: That should be works, I give wrong example both of them is not numeric, in my case, the 'Price' os cellphone number

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Is possible some way distinguish between values in columns - e.g. by str.contains('some_substring') or by check all possible values by `.isin(['a','s','d'])`?